# Owl-carousel 2. Как отобразить цифры в dots?

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

Как можно вместо точек слайдера, отображать цифры (т.е. кол-во слайдов)?
И чтобы он переходил по цифрам, на нужный слайд

Answer (score 1):

```
var i= 1; $('.owl-dot').each(function(){    $(this).find('span').html(i);   i++; });
```